# OpenCV 2.4.X slow on square detection with WebCam vs OpenCV 2.1.X

Tags: opencv, detection

I have tried to port Square detection with OpenCV 2.4.1-2.4.4 but results seem very slow. I was keen to move to newer versions of OpenCV because of new functionality given, but am having very slow results.

My OpenCV code for versions 2.4.X is:

```
// The "Square Detector" program.
// It loads several images sequentially and tries to find squares in
// each image

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int thresh = 50, N = 11;
const char* wndname = "Square Detection Demo";

// helper function:
// finds a cosine of angle between vectors
// from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2
static double angle( Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}

// returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
// the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
static void findSquares( const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    squares.clear();

    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
    pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        // try several threshold levels
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1)*255/N;
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            vector<Point> approx;

            // test each contour
            for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if( approx.size() == 4 &&
                    fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                    isContourConvex(Mat(approx)) )
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                    {
                        // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence
                    if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// the function draws all the squares in the image
static void drawSquares( Mat& image, const vector<vector<Point> >& squares )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
    {
        const Point* p = &squares[i][0];
        int n = (int)squares[i].size();
        polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    imshow(wndname, image);
}


int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    Mat frame,image;


    namedWindow( "Square Detection Demo", 1 );
    vector<vector<Point> > squares;

    for(;;)
    {

        cap >> frame;
        if( frame.empty() ){
            break;
        }


        frame.copyTo(image);

        if( image.empty() )
        {
            cout << "Couldn't load image" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        findSquares(image, squares);
        drawSquares(image, squares);

        //imshow("Window", image);

        int c = waitKey(1);
        if( (char)c == 27 )
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can notice that the code is a simple mix of Webcam visualization and the squares code provided both by OpenCV 2.4.X.

However, the equivalent code for version 2.1 of OpenCV which i will put now is a lot faster:

```
    #include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int thresh = 50;
IplImage* img = 0;
IplImage* img0 = 0;
CvMemStorage* storage = 0;



// helper function:
// finds a cosine of angle between vectors
// from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2
double angle( CvPoint* pt1, CvPoint* pt2, CvPoint* pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1->x - pt0->x;
    double dy1 = pt1->y - pt0->y;
    double dx2 = pt2->x - pt0->x;
    double dy2 = pt2->y - pt0->y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}



// returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
// the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
CvSeq* findSquares4( IplImage* img, CvMemStorage* storage )
{
    CvSeq* contours;
    int i, c, l, N = 11;
    CvSize sz = cvSize( img->width & -2, img->height & -2 );
    IplImage* timg = cvCloneImage( img ); // make a copy of input image
    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1 );

    IplImage* pyr = cvCreateImage( cvSize(sz.width/2, sz.height/2), 8, 3 );
    IplImage* tgray;
    CvSeq* result;
    double s, t;
    // create empty sequence that will contain points -
    // 4 points per square (the square's vertices)
    CvSeq* squares = cvCreateSeq( 0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), storage );

    // select the maximum ROI in the image
    // with the width and height divisible by 2
    cvSetImageROI( timg, cvRect( 0, 0, sz.width, sz.height ));

    //cvSetImageROI( timg, cvRect( 0,0,50, 50 ));

    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    cvPyrDown( timg, pyr, 7 );
    cvPyrUp( pyr, timg, 7 );
    tgray = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1 );

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        // extract the c-th color plane
        cvSetImageCOI( timg, c+1 );
        cvCopy( timg, tgray, 0 );

        // try several threshold levels
        for( l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                cvCanny( tgray, gray, 0, thresh, 5 );
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments
                cvDilate( gray, gray, 0, 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                cvThreshold( tgray, gray, (l+1)*255/N, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            cvFindContours( gray, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
                CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0) );

            // test each contour
            while( contours )
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                result = cvApproxPoly( contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage,
                    CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0 );
                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation


                if( result->total == 4 &&
                    cvContourArea(result,CV_WHOLE_SEQ,0) > 1000 &&
                    cvCheckContourConvexity(result) )
                {
                    s = 0;

                    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
                    {
                        // find minimum angle between joint
                        // edges (maximum of cosine)
                        if( i >= 2 )
                        {
                            t = fabs(angle(
                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ),
                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i-2 ),
                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i-1 )));
                            s = s > t ? s : t;
                        }
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence
                    if( s < 0.3 )
                        for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                            cvSeqPush( squares,
                                (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ));
                }

                // take the next contour
                contours = contours->h_next;
            }
        }
    }

    // release all the temporary images
    cvReleaseImage( &gray );
    cvReleaseImage( &pyr );
    cvReleaseImage( &tgray );
    cvReleaseImage( &timg );

    return squares;
}



// the function draws all the squares in the image
void drawSquares( IplImage* img, CvSeq* squares )
{
    CvSeqReader reader;
    IplImage* cpy = cvCloneImage( img );
    int i;

    // initialize reader of the sequence
    cvStartReadSeq( squares, &reader, 0 );

    // read 4 sequence elements at a time (all vertices of a square)
    for( i = 0; i < squares->total; i += 4 )
    {

        CvPoint pt[4], *rect = pt;
        int count = 4;

        // read 4 vertices
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[0], reader );
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[1], reader );
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[2], reader );
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[3], reader );

        // draw the square as a closed polyline
        cvPolyLine( cpy, &rect, &count, 1, 1, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA, 0 );
    }

    // show the resultant image
    cvShowImage( "Squares", cpy );
    cvReleaseImage( &cpy );
}




int main(int argc, char** argv){

     // Crea una ventana llamada Original Image con un tamaño predeterminado.
    cvNamedWindow("Original Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("Squares", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    // Crea la conexion con la Webcam.
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

    if( !capture ){
        throw "Error when reading steam_avi";
    }

    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    while(true)
        {

        // Pongo el frame capturado dentro de la imagen originalImg.
        img0 = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!img0){
            break;
        }





        img = cvCloneImage( img0 );

        // find and draw the squares
        drawSquares( img, findSquares4( img, storage ) );




        cvShowImage("Original Image", img0);


        cvReleaseImage(&img);   
        // clear memory storage - reset free space position
        cvClearMemStorage( storage );

        // Espero a que me pulsen el ESC para salir del bucle infinito.
        char c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }

    //cvReleaseImage(&img); 
    cvReleaseImage(&img0);

    // clear memory storage - reset free space position
        cvClearMemStorage( storage );
    // Destruye la ventana “Original Image”.
    cvDestroyWindow("Original Image");
    cvDestroyWindow("Squares");
    // Libera la memoria utilizada por la variable capture.
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

I am aware that I can use one colour channel to speed up x3, and change other params to speed up, but wonder why equivalent codes give such different execution times.

Is there anything basic which I am missing out on?

I have tried to put working code up for everyone to try, so as to not waste anybody's time with vague questions such as: Opencv 2.4.X is slow.

Comment: It looks like you're using OpenCV for both capture and processing.  Do you know which half is slow?  Like, can you comment out the processing bits and tell if the capture half is running at expected speed?

Comment: Hi Chris, first off thanks for the reply.
The capture half works fine. When trying out the code, the only part that goes slow in OpenCV2.4.4 is Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5); If I comment it as follows, it goes at a reasonable speed, so if I have to center my attention it should be at this point. I have commented the code and just made a simple copy so it will continue working as follows:
                //Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
    
         gray0.copyTo(gray);
However, now i get the whole frame as a possible square, although smaller ones are also shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly left out Canny and checked for Area of square being below certain values (less 20% of image area) so that unwanted squares were not detected. As for getting multiple results for same square, am not too bothered with it at the moment, as i can input given squares as possible template images for comparisson. Now off to recognition of image in square. Thanks Chris for at least reading this comment (I cant give you points as answer as it was only a comment, but either way, thank you).